# Debian, Beaglebone, WIFI interface works outgoing, not incoming

Tags: linux, debian, embedded-linux, wireless, beagleboneblack

I have a panda wireless card setup on my BeagleBone Black (latest debian image).

From the BBB, I can ping my router, and google.

However, I cannot ping or ssh to the wireless interface of the BBB from another system on my network. I've tried with both static and dhcp configurations.

Here is the wlan0 config in `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
    wireless_mode Managed
    wpa-ssid "MYSSID"
    wpa-psk "PASSWORD"
```

Note that when I am wired up on eth0, I can access the BBB from another system on my network just fine.

Comment: Have you checked Firewall settings or any anti-virus software you've installed?

Comment: There is no av or firewall on the BBB that I am aware of. Also, as I mentioned, it's only an issue over wireless. When I am connected to the ethernet port, I can access it fine.

Comment: have you seen this post http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10035/cannot-connect-to-raspi-by-ssh-with-wifi-interface-only

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same issue.

I was able to access the Internet through `wlan0`, but I wasn't able of ssh/ping the BBB using this interface. 
After wasting a day fiddling with `/etc/network/interfaces` settings, I noticed that `eth0` is up/active after boot, even if the network cable is disconnected at boot time.

If `eth0` is deactivated (ifdown `eth0`) the problem is solved. Plugging and unplugging the network cable has the same effect. After that, I can ping `wlan0` interface from any device in my home network.
Guess that I shall write some script for detecting at boot time whether eth cable is plugged or not, and shutting it down if it isn't.